# Wampserver 2.1 MySQL and localhost problem

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, wampserver, mysql-error-1130

I've been using wampserver for a while but today ive installed new version WampServer 2.1e (32 bits) and I can't understand whats going on.

I can't use MySQL console to login, I always get

> ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'my ip address' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

I am using MySQL 5.5.8.

And when I try to open `http://localhost/anything/anything/anything` or any other addess on localhost I always get moved to `http://localhost/users/login?from=/` to some ADIMIRA Catalogo Metalúrgico.

There is no .htaccess in my www folder and I have even `rewrite_module off`.

Can anyone tell me please what is wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Are you running on win7? And check your DOCROOT for apache, is it pointing to the right place?

Comment: yes im running on win7 and document root in httpd.conf is pointing where it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that you are trying to connect to MySQL using a username that is restricted to either `localhost` or another specific IP address, and either aren't local or aren't connecting using that specific IP address.

You will need to either remove the host restriction from that user, or add another host to the list of hosts that user can connect as.  You'll want to read up on [account management commands in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/account-management-sql.html) to find exactly the right commands for your situation.

(This error can also mean that the restriction is hostname-based, but the IP you're using to connect does not have that hostname *or* the hostname lookup failed.)

Comment: thanks for this, im familiar with account management in MySQL using the SQL commands but the problem is that i cant get into the MySQL commandline at all. When i turn off the internet it refuses the localhost as well as my ip address. The mysql is installed localy and im not trying to access it remotely

Comment: i mean disconnect from the internet so my ip address changes to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Check your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_\(file\)), you might not have an entry in there matching 127.0.0.1 to `localhost`, which can also cause this problem.

Comment: it was the host file... i actually put # comment before localhost because of older version of wampserver but the new one has a problem with that. So its fixed now and thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

From the wampserver site, the latest stable release is 2.1. Where did you get version 2.2 from? Anyway, I think it's better to use the stable versions instead of the beta ones. No point using the latest software if it does not work.

Comment: I have WampServer 2.1e (32 bits)... my mistake